# Linux : SAR shows memory is increasing continously

Tags: linux, memory, performance

Only one application is running on the machine . When I run endurance test with high concurrency for 8 hours , SAR report shows memory usage increasing gradually .  But application heap pattern remains constant and the application uses the memory well within the expected range . But system memory keeps on increasing throughout the time . I can't see any other process using high amount of memory ( using top command ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are confusing memory usage and memory usage ...

As every UNIXy kernel, Linux is expected to use nearly all of the available memory over time: As a disk cache. This does of course not mean, that this portion of memory is lost for other uses - on demand these caches will be dropped to make room for applications etc.

The tool  `free` (most likely used as `free -m`) will show you not only the **free**, but also the **available** memory. You will see, that while the free memory gets less and less over time, the available memory stays roughly the same (unless you actively use it).